# Referencing CLR project from F# project targeting 4.6.1

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a Visual Studio solution (currently using 2017 Community edition) with two projects : one F# library and one C++ CLR. I want to expose stuff from the CLR to the F# library. When I try to add a reference to the CLR project in the F# project, I get an error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer in an [MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yingqin/2013/03/13/integrate-native-c-project-with-managed-c-projects/) :

> Here is a trick that we directly do reference by editing the B_Interop.csproj, as we cannot reference a native project from C# project in Visual Studio.